# php-html email with variable

Tags: php, variables, html-email

Hallo I've got a problem with sending html E-mails with a dyanamic Link via PHP.
That is my PHP Code:

```html
$empfaenger = $_POST['email'];
$test = sha1($_POST['email']);
$betreff = "Test Mail";
$from = "From: Peter <tets@gmail.com>\n";
$from .= "Reply-To: test16@gmail.com\n";
$from .= "Content-Type: text/html\n";
$text = "Please click <p><a href='http://defaultpage/default.php?res=".$test."'>here</a></p>.";
mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text, $from);
```

In the mail Log all looks normal like the mail is sended, but I didn't receive one. In PHP error Log also nothing. If I set $test to a specified string it's working as expected, but not with the dyanamic variable $test. I hope that someone can help me becuse I can't get rid of this problem.

Comment: Use string interpolation `<a href='http://defaultpage/default.php?res={$test}'>`. Not sure what would be stopping the sending but maybe a bad string?

Comment: I trie again couple of times with this method but still nothing.

Comment: If I put html of $text in a text file the link is right:`<p><a href='http://defaultpage/default.php?res=96163c3fbf450aa723c8e50474b469b1841e68b3'>here</a></p>`

Comment: If you are working on a windows then you have to use `\r\n` at the end of each line instead of `\n`. or maybe it's better to use `PHP_EOL` instead of them...

Comment: I had not much time to try but first this seemed to work just fine.

Comment: OK I now tested it out completly. It's working just fine. the `\r\n` must have been the problem.